# How to replace nonNumeric value in Column value with 0 in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a Column which has the percentage values,i have a infinity symbol as one of value.But i need to replace all the non numeric values with 0's .How can i replace all non numeric values to  0?

```
=Iif(IsNumeric(fields!JulyRevenue.Value/Fields!JulyQuota.Value) ,(fields!JulyRevenue.Value/Fields!JulyQuota.Value),"0")
```

Is the above expression correct.Still i am getting the infinity value

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend converting infinity to zero. But I think you need something like this:

```
=iif(Fields!JulyQuota.Value=0 , 0, (fields!JulyRevenue.Value/Fields!JulyQuota.Value))
```